# AngularJS intercept ng-switch and do something?

Tags: angularjs

I have two views that are in element directives. To determine which one is shown, its controlled by a single scope variable in my applications primary controller. Is there a way whenever the "ng-switch" changes on the scope variable "a", do some specific set of functions?

Is there an alternative to $scope.watch? I am looking for a solution that is the least performance intensive.

Comment: Is `a` the scope Variable deciding which view to be shown?

Comment: Yes. If it is "A", it shows directiveA, if it is "B" it shows directiveB

Comment: Can these specific set of functions be called inside your Directive's link function.So that every time the directive is loaded those specific functions executes .

Comment: Yes I could, but the problem is I have 3 directives that all do very similar things. I am not sure if it makes sense to "enforce the rule" that all directives must call those specific functions, or if there is a better way to be smart about it by calling it outside of the directives.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ng-if which creates/destroys a HTML element, although it is not very angular like philosophy.
HTML:

```
<div ng-init="runAInstructions()" ng-if="runInstruct">0</div>
<div ng-init="runBInstructions()" ng-if="!runInstruct">1</div>

<div ng-click="runInstruct = !runInstruct">Click here!</div>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.runInstruct = true;

    $scope.runAInstructions = function(){
        console.log("A");
    }
    $scope.runBInstructions = function(){
        console.log("B");
    }
```

Or, you simply execute function A or B which you determine in the controller when you press Button "Click here". So remove ng-init, and write like:

```
<div ng-click="determineInstruct()">Click here!</div>
```

in JS:

```
    $scope.determineInstruct = function(){
        ($scope.runInstruct) ? $scope.runAInstructions() :  $scope.runBInstructions();
    }
```

Or lastly, simply determining in each function, avoiding the 3rd function, write it like:

```
<div ng-if="runA()">0</div>
<div ng-if="!runB()">1</div>


    $scope.runA = function(){
        if ($scope.runInstruct){
            console.log("run A instructions here")
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    $scope.runB = function(){
        if (!$scope.runInstruct){
            console.log("run B instructions here")
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You could also use ng-hide/ng-show which doesn't destroy the element and is evaluated each $digest cycle.